# Differential geometry - For any vector in $R^n$ there exists a velocity vector $\gamma\prime(t)$ of closed curve $\gamma$ which is orthogonal to it

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I have the following problem.
Suppose that I have smooth (regular) closed curve $\gamma: [a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$.
I need to prove that for every vector $\phi\in\mathbb R^n$ there exists point $t\in[a,b]$ such as the value of the velocity speed vector at this point ($\gamma\prime(t))$ is orthogonal to this vector.

My approach (Intuition) was to assume that if it isn't true then for any vector $\gamma=(r_1,...,r_n)$ and for any point $t$ the velocity speed vector at this point (i.e. derivative vector) isn't orthogonal to this vector so the curve isn't turning back to the origin point $\gamma(a)$ and therefore it will not be closed eventually (at point $b$) and this will give me a contradiction to the fact that this is a closed curve, But I'm really struggling with how to convert my approach to formal proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume

$\phi \ne 0, \tag 0$

since the notion of orthogonality is at best trivial and at worst meaningless when (0) fails.

Consider the function

$f(t) = \phi \cdot \gamma(t); \tag 1$

since $\gamma(t)$ is a closed regular curve on $[a, b]$, a compact interval, the function $f(t)$ attains its extremal values on $[a, b]$; at such a

$\tau \in [a, b] \tag 2$

we have

$\phi  \cdot \gamma'(\tau) = f'(\tau) = 0; \tag 3$

but this is precisely the assertion that $\gamma'(\tau)$ is orthogonal to $\phi$. ***$OE\Delta$***

***Note Added in Edit, Saturday 7 November 2020 12:47 PM PST:***  The geometry of this situation may perhaps be further illuminated bye scrutinizing the meaning of $f(t)$: if we write $\phi$ in polar form:

$\phi = \vert \phi \vert \mathbf e_\phi, \tag 4$

where

$\mathbf e_\phi \in S^{n - 1} \tag 5$

is the unit vector in the direction of $\phi$, then $f(t)$ becomes

$f(t)= \vert \phi \vert \mathbf e_\phi \cdot \gamma(t); \tag 6$

aside from the factor of $\vert \phi \vert$, the quantity $f(t)$ is the component of $\gamma(t) \in \Bbb R^n$ along $\mathbf e_\phi$; $\vert \phi \vert > 0$ may then be seen as an arbitrary (constant) scaling factor, and there is no loss of information by taking $\vert \phi \vert = 1$; then

$f(t) = \mathbf e_\phi \cdot \gamma(t) \tag 7$

is of itself *precisely* the component of $\gamma(t)$ along $\mathbf e_\phi$, and this component is extremal at $\tau$ such that

$f'(\tau) = \mathbf e_\phi \cdot \gamma'(\tau) = 0, \tag 8$

that is, where $\gamma'(\tau)$ is normal to $\mathbf e_\phi$; hence we may think of $\gamma'(\tau)$ as tangent to or lying in the hyperplane normal to $\mathbf e_\phi$ passing through $\gamma(\tau)$.

We may in fact find the second derivitive of $f(t)$:

$f''(t) = \mathbf e_\phi \cdot \gamma''(t), \tag9$

which of course provides information aas to the nature of an extremum $\tau$; when

$f''(\tau) > 0, \tag{10}$

then $\tau$ is a local minumum, and so forth and so on..

A more geometric approach is had by parametrizing $\gamma(s)$ by its arc-length $s$; then

$\dot \gamma(s) = T(s), \tag{11}$

the unit tangent vector field to $\gamma(s)$.  Then

$f'(s) = \mathbf e_\phi \cdot \dot \gamma(s) = \mathbf e_\phi \cdot T(s); \tag{12}$

proceeding in this direction, we have

$f''(s) = \mathbf e_\phi \cdot \ddot \gamma(s) = \mathbf e_\phi \cdot \dot T(s) = \mathbf e_\phi \cdot \kappa(s) N(s), \tag{13}$

where we have used the [Frenet-Serret relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas)

$\dot T(s) = \kappa(s) N{s}, \tag{14}$

where

$\kappa(s) > 0 \tag{15}$

is the curvature, and $N(s)$ is the unit normal vector to $\gamma(s)$.  In light of (15) we see that the sign of $f''(s)$ is given by $\mathbf e_\phi \cdot N(s)$, that is,

$f''(s) > 0 \tag{16}$

when $\gamma(s)$ is turning toward the positive side of the hyperplane normal to $\mathbf e_\phi$, which side is in fact characterized by the equation

$X \cdot \mathbf e_\phi - Y \cdot \mathbf e_\phi = (X - Y) \cdot \mathbf e_\phi >  0, \tag{17}$

where $Y \in \Bbb R^n$ lies in the hyperplane itself and $X \in \Bbb R^n$ on the positive side.  (Under these hypotheses on $X$ and $Y$,

***End of Note.***

Comment: @Alex Provost:  thanks for the small grammatical edit. ***Cheers!***

Comment: @michael: In your statement of the problem you specified "$t \in [a, b]$" so I assumed it's OK if the maximum occurs at $a$ or $b$; I mean, it seems you've allowed this.

Comment: Thank you! It was well explained (basically my intuition was closer to the new part that you've added to your comment).   
By the way, does your proof also applies to curve that is just smooth (i.e. not closed)? In this case we don't know the value of $\gamma\prime$ on the edges of the interval (just one side derivative can be calculated)...   
From what I understand from what you've written we will get the same solution in this case either (am I missing something here?)

Comment: @michael:  good questions.  Unfortunately, it is rather late here so I'll try to answer tomorrow.

Comment: After I thought about it, I have come to the conclusion that this lemma doesn't apply to curve that isn't closed but smooth because what I've wrote above that the derivative can't be determined at the edges of the interval but on open segment $(x,y)\in[a,b]$